# Disable ViewPager Swipe From Right To Left and Left To Right Side

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am using ViewPager in one of my android application. I am learning yet Android and so does not know much about it. I want disable swipe from left to right and right to left on position based. I have searched in stackoverflow for solution but not got any proper solution. I am attaching my code here. Let me know if someone can help me to solve this puzzle.

**My ViewPager**

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            constant.new_ad_count = constant.new_ad_count + 1;
            mItemIndx = position;
            try {
                int index = position % ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
                currentQuote = quotes.get(index);
            } catch
                    (Exception e) {
            }
            mPageIndx = ((position + 1) / ITEMS_PER_PAGE) + (((position + 1) % ITEMS_PER_PAGE) > 0 ? 1 : 0);
            updateUI();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(mItemIndx);
    updateUI();
}
```

**Function From Which I want Disable Swipe**

```
private void updateUI() {

    lblLikeCount.setText(currentQuote.getQuLike());
    lblShareCount.setText(currentQuote.getQuShare());
    lblTime.setText(currentQuote.getQuTime());
    textPageCount.setText((mItemIndx + 1) + " / " + totalSize);
    // butNext.setVisibility((mItemIndx < totalSize - 1) ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    butPrev.setVisibility((mItemIndx > 0) ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    if(mItemIndx==totalSize-1||(mItemIndx+1)%ITEMS_PER_PAGE==0) {
        butNext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        //I want Disable Right to Left Swipe Here
    } else {
        butNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (mItemIndx-1<0 ||(mItemIndx)%ITEMS_PER_PAGE==0) {
        butPrev.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        //I want Disable Left to Right Here
    } else {
        butPrev.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

Thanks a lot Friends :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a this `NonSwipableViewPager` class, using this, you will only be able to change the page when calling `setCurrentItem`.

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setMyScroller();
    }

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setMyScroller();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    //down one is added for smooth scrolling

    private void setMyScroller() {
        try {
            Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
            Field scroller = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
            scroller.setAccessible(true);
            scroller.set(this, new MyScroller(getContext()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class MyScroller extends Scroller {
        public MyScroller(Context context) {
            super(context, new DecelerateInterpolator());
        }

        @Override
        public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
            super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, 350 /*1 secs*/);
        }
    }
```

Add this class to your project, then in the layout where you want it, replace `ViewPager` with:

```
<yourpackagename.NonSwipeableViewPager
```

Then initialise it in your Activity or Fragment:

```
NonSwipeableViewPager pager = (NonSwipeableViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
```